# Text extends out of <div> once in <p> tag?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do something very simple. I want my text to stay contained within my     `<div>`. I was having this problem earlier with two floating `div`s. I tried clearing them, and using word-wrap however that did not solve the problem. So I put that on hold then moved on to something new.

While creating another `div` that was not floating, I noticed once I placed the text inside the `<p></p>` tag, the text extended outside the `div` again. I know this because initially I forgot to place the text in the `<p>` tag, and the text stayed in the box. Once I corrected it, the text extended out again. Please help. I am pulling my hair out for what I know should be something simple.

Side Note: I do not want to use `overflow:scroll;`. I don't have enough text for that.

```css
#topNews {
    width: 625px;
    height: 220px;
    position: relative;
    font-family: Arial Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-bottom: solid #7e7d7d thin;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -30px;
    margin-top: -15px;
}

#about {
    width: 320px;
    height: 180px;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    border: dashed red thin;
}
```

```html
<div id="topNews">
    <div id="about">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et turpis sed metus fermentum pellentesque. Vestibulum auctor neque ac nunc elementum malesuada. Praesent non est sed libero vestibulum consectetuer. Sed vehicula. Vivamus quis tellus sit amet erat ultrices luctus. Fusce a ligula. Fusce viverra libero vitae velit.
        </p>              
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean by "out of the div", but the nested div inherits `margin-left` and `margin-top` from `#topnews`. If you compensate in `#about` with positive values, does that fix your issue?

Comment: For example http://jsfiddle.net/G85ZT/ ?

Comment: i use inspector in chrome and firebug in firefox to play with the css.  you can visually see the elements and where their styles are coming from. you can even manipulate them live to see what change it makes

Answer (score 1):

Its Gone out of `div` because

```
#topNews {  
    width: 625px;  
    height: 220px;  
    position: relative;  
    font-family: Arial Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
    font-size: 14px;  
    border-bottom: solid #7e7d7d thin;   
    float: left;  
    margin-left: -30px;  
    margin-top: -15px;  
}
```

In your code you specifies margin with -ve value. So its starting position may be in -ve x-axis.

Use +ve x-axis values...
like

```
 margin-left: 0px;  
 margin-top: 0px;
```

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/StXNK/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Text IS inside a div, its just the div is positioned out of you view because you used:

```
margin-left: -30px;
margin-top: -15px;
```

check out this image: [click](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/26827941/Screenshot%20from%202012-11-15%2006:02:28.png) (i edited -30 and -15 to 0 and 0)

to make your job easier in future, use developer tools (f12 by default)

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I will scrub through my other CSS docs to see if I find anything out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried out your sample code and the text is contained in the DIV properly ..

Comment: it looks fine to me as well.  I'm on chrome

Comment: I have like 4 other css pages. Is it possible that something in one of those could be causing the issue?

Comment: arun is right, im not sure why is he being downvoted, text is positioned inside a div, its just the div that is out of viewport because of -margins

Comment: most probably something else is causing the problem .. this css is proper , just position the div properly

Comment: This isn't really an answer, would have been more suitable in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will helpful for you.

**HTML**

```
<div id="topNews">
    <div id="about">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et turpis sed metus fermentum pellentesque. Vestibulum auctor neque ac nunc elementum malesuada. Praesent non est sed libero vestibulum consectetuer. Sed vehicula. Vivamus quis tellus sit amet erat ultrices luctus. Fusce a ligula. Fusce viverra libero vitae velit.
        </p>              
    </div>

    <div id="about">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et turpis sed metus fermentum pellentesque. Vestibulum auctor neque ac nunc elementum malesuada. Praesent non est sed libero vestibulum consectetuer. Sed vehicula. Vivamus quis tellus sit amet erat ultrices luctus. Fusce a ligula. Fusce viverra libero vitae velit.
        </p>              
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#topNews{
    width:625px;
    height:220px;
    position:relative;
    font-family:Arial Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-bottom:solid #7e7d7d thin;
}

#about{
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:3px;
    margin-left:3px;
    margin-top:7px;
    padding:5px;
    border: dashed red thin;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have css somewhere after that changes the size of your p tag.  Also if you have anything with a width of 100% (ie: `width: 100%;`), it's always 100% plus the size of your margins/padding which would make elements stick out.